# show one loader for 4 async tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader

I have an activity in which there are 4 async task.

In that the array is being filled.Now till the time the data is loaded from API i want to show loader and when the array is filled it should disappears.

I know how to show loader for one async task but how can I show one loader for 4 async task.

Can anyone help on this?
If any other information is needed, please let know.

Comment: are you calling all 4 async task simultaneously or one after another?

Comment: Yes...calling one after another

Comment: you can show loader in first Async and call other async in onPostExecute() of previous one. and dismiss it in last Async onPostExecute()

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1. Keep on starting another AsyncTask in the onPostExecute of the prior AsyncTask.
2. Keep the 4 AsyncTasks in an array. Now create another AsyncTask and in it's doInBackground, keep a while loop running, keep on calling the `getStatus()` of each task and check whether it has `FINISHED`. Once the status of all four is `FINISHED`, then return this AsyncTask's  doInBackground and in it's onPostExecute, close the loader.